# How to predict y value for given time in Kaplan-Meier curve

Tags: r, survival-analysis

In a Kaplan-Meier curve, how can I predict the *y* value for a given time.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to have anyone answering your questions you should provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty good example given on http://www.cancerguide.org/scurve_km.html

Comment: The link does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Fit a Model to your data, the you can predict from this model.
See the `survival` package and the examples therein.